# F# pattern matching on records with optional fields

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, field, record, option-type

F#'s 'options' seem a nice way of using the type system to separate data that's known to be present from data which may or may not be present, and I like the way that the `match` expression enforces that all cases are considered:

```
match str with
| Some s -> functionTakingString(s)
| None -> "abc"         // The compiler would helpfully complain if this line wasn't present
```

It's very useful that `s` (opposed to `str`) is a `string` rather than a `string option`.

However, when working with records that have optional fields...

```
type SomeRecord =
    {
        field1 : string
        field2 : string option
    }
```

...and those records are being filtered, a `match` expression *feels* unnecessary, because there's nothing sensible to do in the `None` case, but this...

```
let functionTakingSequenceOfRecords mySeq =
    mySeq
    |> Seq.filter (fun record -> record.field2.IsSome)
    |> Seq.map (fun record -> functionTakingString field2)          // Won't compile
```

... won't compile, because although records where `field2` isn't populated have been filtered out, the type of `field2` is still `string option`, not `string`.

I could define another record type, where `field2` isn't optional, but that approach seems complicated, and may be unworkable with many optional fields.

I've defined an operator that raises an exception if an option is `None`...

```
let inline (|?!) (value : 'a option) (message : string) =
    match value with
    | Some x -> x
    | None -> invalidOp message
```

...and have changed the previous code to this...

```
let functionTakingSequenceOfRecords mySeq =
    mySeq
    |> Seq.filter (fun record -> record.field2.IsSome)
    |> Seq.map (fun record -> functionTakingString (record.field2 |?! "Should never happen"))           // Now compiles
```

...but it doesn't seem ideal. I could use `Unchecked.defaultof` instead of raising an exception, but I'm not sure that's any better. The crux of it is that the `None` case isn't relevant after filtering.

Are there any better ways of handling this?

**EDIT**

The very interesting answers have brought record pattern matching to my attention, which I wasn't aware of, and `Value`, which I'd seen but misunderstood (I see that it throws a `NullReferenceException` if `None`). But I think my example may have been poor, as my more complex, real-life problem involves using more than one field from the record. I suspect I'm stuck with something like...

```
|> Seq.map (fun record -> functionTakingTwoStrings record.field1 record.field2.Value)
```

unless there's something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this example, you could use:

```
let functionTakingSequenceOfRecords mySeq =
    mySeq
    |> Seq.choose (fun { field2 = v } -> v)
    |> Seq.map functionTakingString
```

`Seq.choose` allows us to filter items based on optional results. Here we you pattern matching on records for more concise code.

I think the general idea is to manipulate option values using combinators, high-order functions until you would like to transform them into values of other types (e.g. using `Seq.choose` in this case). Using your `|?!` is discouraged because it is a partial operator (throwing exceptions in some cases). You can argue that it's safe to use in this particular case; but F# type system can't detect it and warn you about unsafe use in any case.

On a side note, I would recommend to take a look at Railway-Oriented Programming series at http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/. The series show you type-safe and composable ways to handle errors where you can keep diagnostic information along.

**UPDATE** (upon your edit):

A revised version of your function is written as follows:

```
let functionTakingSequenceOfRecords mySeq =
    mySeq
    |> Seq.choose (fun { field1 = v1; field2 = v2 } -> 
         v2 |> Option.map (functionTakingString v1))
```

It demonstrates the general idea I mentioned where you manipulate option values using high-order functions (`Option.map`) and transform them at a final step (`Seq.choose`).

Comment: Thanks for the very interesting answer. I'm not sure I can use the record pattern matching, as per the EDIT in my question above, but thanks also for the Railway-Oriented Programming link.

Comment: @Giles: I revised my answer based on your edit. I think my general idea is still valid. You should strive for type-safe ways of transforming values.

Comment: Thanks very much for the update. it may take me a little while to fully digest, but I think I get the gist! Would it be fair to say that the potential downside is that with a record with many fields, it'd be necessary to bind all the fields as per v1 and v2?

Comment: Yes. In that case, Maybe computation expression will be handy to use.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have found the `IsSome` property, you might have seen the `Value` property as well.

```
let functionTakingSequenceOfRecords mySeq =
    mySeq
    |> Seq.filter (fun record -> record.field2.IsSome)
    |> Seq.map (fun record -> functionTakingString record.field2.Value )
```

There's an alternative with pattern matching:

```
let functionTakingSequenceOfRecords' mySeq =
    mySeq
    |> Seq.choose (function
        | { field2 = Some v } ->  functionTakingString v |> Some
        | _ -> None )
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting `.Value` - I'd seen it but misunderstood. I like the record pattern matching, but as per the EDIT in my question, I'm not sure I can use it. Unless...  :o)

Comment: @Giles  To make the matching more versatile, you could introduce more `record patterns` as needed, or use an `"as" pattern` to bind the whole pattern to a variable (e.g. `| { field2 = Some v } as record -> ...`).

Comment: Thanks for another pointer - I shall read up on the "as" pattern. My first week on F# and I'm realising there's a lot more to know than I've picked up so far!

Answer (score 2):

The problem as I interpreted is that you want to have the type system at all times reflecting the fact that those records in the collection actually contains a string in field2.

I mean, for sure you can use `choose` to filter out the records you don't care but still you will end up with a collection of records with an optional string and you know all of them would be Some string.

One alternative is to create a generic record like this:

```
type SomeRecord<'T> =
{
    field1 : string
    field2 : 'T
}
```

But then you can't use record expression to clone the record and change the generic type of the record at the same time. You will need to create the new record by hand, which will not be a major problem if the other fields are not so many and the structure is stable.

The other option is to wrap the record in a tuple with the desired value, here's an example:

```
let functionTakingSequenceOfRecords mySeq =
    let getField2 record = 
        match record with
        | {field2 = Some value} -> Some (value, record)
        | _ -> None

    mySeq
    |> Seq.choose getField2
    |> Seq.map (fun (f2, {field1 = f1}) -> functionTakingTwoStrings f1 f2)
```

So here you ignore the content of field2 and use instead the first value in the tuple.

Unless I misunderstood your problem and you don't care pattern matching again, or doing an incomplete matching with a warning or a #nowarn directive or using the `.Value` property of the option as shown in the other answers.

Comment: Thanks - both the generic record and the approach with tuples are interesting alternatives.